# Portable Class Library (PCL) Contrib - Cryptography

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography, portable-class-library

I want to use the cryptography in the [Portable Class Library Contrib project on codeplex](http://pclcontrib.codeplex.com/) but have not found any documentation on how I can use it.

I want to create a wrapper class with `Encrypt` and `Decrypt` methods inside it and I want this wrapper class to exist in a portable class library. I have referenced `Portable.Runtime` and `Portable.Security.Cryptography` in this project. Is this correct?

I then want to use my wrapper inside a .NET, Windows Phone and Metro project. In these projects I reference my wrapper project, `Portable.Runtime`, `Portable.Security.Cryptography` and the corresponding Portable project i.e. `Portable.Desktop`, `Portable.Phone` or `Portable.WindowsStore`. Is this correct?

I get conflicting namespace errors when I try to use my wrapper class however. This is the error and my wrapper class:

> The type `System.Security.Cryptography.AesManaged` exists in both `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\Profile\Client\System.Core.dll` and `C:\Downloads\PclContrib\bin\Debug\Portable.Security.Cryptography.dll`

```
public sealed class SymmetricCryptography<T> where T : SymmetricAlgorithm, new()
{
    private readonly T provider = new T();
    private readonly UTF8Encoding utf8 = new UTF8Encoding();

    private byte[] key;
    private byte[] iv;

    public byte[] Key
    {
        get { return this.key; }
    }

    public byte[] IV
    {
        get { return this.iv; }
    }

    public SymmetricCryptography()
    {
        this.key = this.provider.Key;
        this.iv = this.provider.IV;
    }

    public SymmetricCryptography(byte[] key, byte[] iv)
    {
        this.key = key;
        this.iv = iv;
    }

    public SymmetricCryptography(string password, string salt)
    {
        Rfc2898DeriveBytes deriveBytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, this.utf8.GetBytes(salt));
        this.key = deriveBytes.GetBytes(this.provider.KeySize >> 3);
        this.iv = deriveBytes.GetBytes(16);
    }

    public SymmetricCryptography(string password, string salt, int iterations)
    {
        Rfc2898DeriveBytes deriveBytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, this.utf8.GetBytes(salt), iterations);
        this.key = deriveBytes.GetBytes(this.provider.KeySize >> 3);
        this.iv = deriveBytes.GetBytes(16);
    }

    public byte[] Encrypt(byte[] input)
    {
        return this.Encrypt(input, this.key, this.iv);
    }

    public byte[] Encrypt(byte[] input, byte[] key, byte[] iv)
    {
        return this.Transform(
            input,
            this.provider.CreateEncryptor(key, iv));
    }

    public byte[] Decrypt(byte[] input)
    {
        return this.Decrypt(input, this.key, this.iv);
    }

    public byte[] Decrypt(byte[] input, byte[] key, byte[] iv)
    {
        return this.Transform(
            input,
            this.provider.CreateDecryptor(key, iv));
    }

    public string Encrypt(string text)
    {
        return this.Encrypt(text, this.key, this.iv);
    }

    public string Encrypt(string text, byte[] key, byte[] iv)
    {
        byte[] output = this.Transform(
            this.utf8.GetBytes(text),
            this.provider.CreateEncryptor(key, iv));
        return Convert.ToBase64String(output);
    }

    public string Decrypt(string text)
    {
        return this.Decrypt(text, this.key, this.iv);
    }

    public string Decrypt(string text, byte[] key, byte[] iv)
    {
        byte[] output = this.Transform(
            Convert.FromBase64String(text),
            this.provider.CreateDecryptor(key, iv));
        return this.utf8.GetString(output, 0, output.Length);
    }

    public void Encrypt(Stream input, Stream output)
    {
        this.Encrypt(input, output, this.key, this.iv);
    }

    public void Encrypt(Stream input, Stream output, byte[] key, byte[] iv)
    {
        this.TransformStream(true, ref input, ref output, key, iv);
    }

    public void Decrypt(Stream input, Stream output)
    {
        this.Decrypt(input, output, this.key, this.iv);
    }

    public void Decrypt(Stream input, Stream output, byte[] key, byte[] iv)
    {
        this.TransformStream(false, ref input, ref output, key, iv);
    }

    private byte[] Transform(
        byte[] input,
        ICryptoTransform cryptoTransform)
    {
        byte[] result;

        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (CryptoStream cryptStream = new CryptoStream(
                memoryStream,
                cryptoTransform,
                CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                cryptStream.Write(input, 0, input.Length);
                cryptStream.FlushFinalBlock();
                memoryStream.Position = 0;
                result = memoryStream.ToArray();
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    private void TransformStream(bool encrypt, ref Stream input, ref Stream output, byte[] key, byte[] iv)
    {
        // defensive argument checking
        if (input == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("input");
        }

        if (output == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("output");
        }

        if (!input.CanRead)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Unable to read from the input Stream.", "input");
        }

        if (!output.CanWrite)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Unable to write to the output Stream.", "output");
        }

        // make the buffer just large enough for 
        // the portion of the stream to be processed
        byte[] inputBuffer = new byte[input.Length - input.Position];
        // read the stream into the buffer
        input.Read(inputBuffer, 0, inputBuffer.Length);
        // transform the buffer
        byte[] outputBuffer = encrypt ? Encrypt(inputBuffer, key, iv)
                                        : Decrypt(inputBuffer, key, iv);
        // write the transformed buffer to our output stream 
        output.Write(outputBuffer, 0, outputBuffer.Length);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you solved your problem, post the solution as an answer, instead of editing it into the question. Or do you have any remaining questions? If so, you should state them explicitly.

Comment: btw your IV use is bad. The IV should be different for each encryption you perform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that my generic wrapper for the cryptography algorithms was causing a problem. PCL Contrib contains a class called SymmetricAlgorithm which is itself a wrapper for the real SymmetricAlgorithm. If I make my wrapper class non-generic it works like this:

```
public sealed class AesManagedSymmetricCryptography : SymmetricCryptography<AesManaged>
{
    #region Constructors

    public AesManagedSymmetricCryptography()
    {
    }

    public AesManagedSymmetricCryptography(byte[] key, byte[] iv)
        : base(key, iv)
    {
    }

    public AesManagedSymmetricCryptography(string password, string salt)
        : base(password, salt)
    {
    }

    public AesManagedSymmetricCryptography(string password, string salt, int iterations)
        : base(password, salt, iterations)
    {
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Can you also include an example of a few lines using this functions?

Comment: I am also trying to use pcl-contrib cryptography to serve both windows phone 8 and windows store apps. 

So I did copy your code from question 
and removed "sealed" from it
   `public class SymmetricCryptography<T> where T : SymmetricAlgorithm, new() ....`

so I can create a non generic version of it, like you suggested.
Could you please post somewhere a solution using this?

Comment: You have used `this.provider.KeySize` but the provider is SymmetricAlgorithm, and it doesn't have KeySize?

Comment: Also `CryptoStream` is not found by compiler. Should I add a reference?
Forgive me for many small questions. I just spent too long to get cryptography working...
Thanks for your understanding...

Comment: I see that CryptoStream is available for .Net 4.5 but it is not available for PCL. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.cryptostream.aspx

If you implemented yours, can you please share?

Comment: I found CryptoStream in Mono implementation:
https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/corlib/System.Security.Cryptography/CryptoStream.cs
but it refers to other files in their implementation of System.Security.Cryptography
Maybe I should just get full library from them:
https://github.com/mono/mono/tree/master/mcs/class/corlib/System.Security.Cryptography
would it work with PCL?

Answer (score 3):

The docs are a little lacking, but I call this out in the [FAQ](http://pclcontrib.codeplex.com/documentation):

> **Can I share the types from PclContrib with my platform-specific projects?** No, not currently. While the types in PclContrib look and
>   feel like their platform-specific counterparts, the runtime and
>   compiler will see them as completely different types. While we have
>   some ideas on how to make this work, this is a feature that we won't
>   be looking at for the short term.

Answer (score 2):

The following .net code works on Desktop implementation.
First add references to Portable.Desktop and Portable.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData

```
   private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String encrypted = PCL.CentralClass.Encrypt("yo");
        String decreypted = PCL.CentralClass.Decrypt(encrypted);
        //PCL.CentralClass.
    }
    //https://pclcontrib.codeplex.com/documentation?FocusElement=Comment
    //\Source\Portable.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData\Security\Cryptography\ProtectedData.cs

    static byte[] GetBytes(string str)
    {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[str.Length * sizeof(char)];
        System.Buffer.BlockCopy(str.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        return bytes;
    }

    static string GetString(byte[] bytes)
    {
        char[] chars = new char[bytes.Length / sizeof(char)];
        System.Buffer.BlockCopy(bytes, 0, chars, 0, bytes.Length);
        return new string(chars);
    }

    public static String Encrypt(String strEncrypt)
    {
        byte[] userData = GetBytes(strEncrypt);
        byte[] optionalEntropy = null;
        byte[] x = System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData.Protect(userData, optionalEntropy);
        return GetString(x);
    }
    public static String Decrypt(String strDecrypt)
    {
        byte[] encryptedData = GetBytes(strDecrypt);
        byte[] optionalEntropy = null;
        byte[] x = System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData.Unprotect(encryptedData, optionalEntropy);
        return GetString(x); ;
    }
```