# Upload file to Amazon S3 bucket from .Net Portable Class Library?

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, portable-class-library

I'm using a PCL in a cross-platform mobile .Net (Xamarin) project. When I try to install the Amazon SDK via Nuget into my PCL it fails.

All I need to do is upload some photos to my S3 bucket. What is the simplest way to accomplish this, either by using some other PCL-friendly library, or just via the .net http library?

Comment: Please read the [AWS documentation regarding creating objects using HTTP](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectPUT.html).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Mikael. I'd already looked through that documentation. Creating an authorization string seems to be a pretty complicated task in C#, especially in a PCL where the Cryptography namespace does not exist. If anyone knows of PCL-friendly C# examples of this, I'd be grateful.

Comment: I see. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12688296/portable-class-library-pcl-contrib-cryptography